# understanding jobs conf.xml parameter pig.script.features

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

What does the parameter

```
<property>
    <name>pig.script.features</name>
    <value>66080</value>
</property>
```

in jobs _*****_conf.xml indicate?

Can it be useful for tuning up the hadoop cluster/ pig workflows?
Is there a list of such parameters available on net with the interpretation of their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter comes from [PIG-1333](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1333) and it is actually nothing more than a compact representation of the script-level features. You see an integer value, but it's in fact a bit set which is used to determine which features are used in the overall Pig script (not just at the job level)

Regarding the features themselves, you can look at the following enum:

```
static enum PIG_FEATURE {
     UNKNOWN,
     MERGE_JION,
     REPLICATED_JOIN,
     SKEWED_JOIN,
     HASH_JOIN,
     COLLECTED_GROUP,
     MERGE_COGROUP,
     COGROUP,
     GROUP_BY,
     ORDER_BY,
     DISTINCT,
     STREAMING,
     SAMPLING,
     MULTI_QUERY,
     FILTER,
     MAP_ONLY,
     CROSS,
     LIMIT,
     UNION,
     COMBINER;
};
```

Now to convert from your bit set (in your case 66080), you can apply the following algorithm that can be found in Pig's source code (where l is your bitset value):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<PIG_FEATURE.values().length; i++) {
    if (((l >> i) & 0x00000001) != 0) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(",");
        sb.append(PIG_FEATURE.values()[i].name());
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

So for example by running it on your bitset, you can see that you had the following features in your Pig script:

- COLLECTED_GROUP
- ORDER_BY
- CROSS

Comment: Thanks a lot @Charles , thats very helpful. Is there a central location where I can get this kind of information regarding all/most of the parameters?